# How do I get a Canon PIXMA ip1900 to work?

Tags: drivers, 10.10, 64-bit, printing, canon

I have a new canon photo printer (pixma ip1900) and I have a minor problem - the deb for it is 32bit and my system is 64bit.

I can use the ppd file in the deb, but I need some pstcanonij program that doesn't seem to be in the repos. How do I get this printer to work? I need it for business!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to recreate the packages on my 32bit Ubuntu install, I couldn't test them on 64bit, but I did show that it's possible to build them for 64bit:

Download this file: http://files.canon-europe.com/files/soft31335/software/iP1900_debian_printer.tar (7.7MB)

Unpack it on your desktop and grab the `cnijfilter-common-3.00-1.tar.gz` file (ignore the deb files), extract this archive and you should get a `cnijfilter-common-3.00` folder. Now you need to go into the terminal and use these commands:

```
cd Desktop/cnijfilter-common-3.00
sudo apt-get install libcupsys2-dev libxml2-dev libtiff4-dev
debuild -i -us -uc -b
```

This should in theory make for you a set of 64bit drivers, both the pimxa ip1900 and the common deb files (as well a bunch of other debs) on your desktop. Install the ones you need and delete everything when finished. If it doesn't work, please report back here.

Comment: WOW - I haven't tested this yet (very tired from work) but I will let you know if it works. I'm pretty confident it will ^^! Thank you so much :D!!!!!!!!!!!