# Canon pixma iP1900 ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

i have been trying to get this old piece of HW working under UBUNTU 20.04. Finally, I came to a old solution ([How do I get a Canon PIXMA ip1900 to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24399/how-do-i-get-a-canon-pixma-ip1900-to-work)). My attempts to recreate it lead me to do following additional steps:

1. edit debian/control to require libcups2-dev instead of libcupsys2-dev and libtiff5-dev instead of libtiff-dev (these packages are no longer available)
2. edit debian/compat to 9 instead of 4. No idea why, i admitt. But it seemed to be working. But then...

   ```
    $ debuild -i -us -uc -b
    dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui -i -b
    dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package cnijfilter-common
    dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 3.00-1
    dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution stable
    dpkg-buildpackage: info: source changed by Canon Inc. <sup-debian@list.canon.co.jp>
     dpkg-source -i --before-build .
    dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
     fakeroot debian/rules clean
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    rm -f build-stamp configure-stamp
    # Add here commands to clean up after the build process.
    /usr/bin/make clean
    make[1]: Entering directory „/media/***/***/tiskatna/cnijfilter-common-3.00“
    target=clean; for dir in libs cngpij pstocanonij backend; do (cd $dir; make $target)|| exit 1; done
    make[2]: Entering directory „/media/***/***/tiskatna/cnijfilter-common-3.00/libs“
    make[2]: *** "No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop."
    make[2]: Leaving directory „/media/***/***/tiskatna/cnijfilter-common-3.00/libs“
    make[1]: *** [Makefile:12: clean] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory „/media/***/***/tiskatna/cnijfilter-common-3.00“
    make: [debian/rules:74: clean] Error 2 (ignored)
    dh_clean 
     debian/rules build
    dh_testdir
    # Add here commands to configure the package.
    ### configure common package
    ######## configure libs

    **Error**: You must have `libtool' installed.
    Get ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libtool-1.2d.tar.gz
    (or a newer version if it is available)
    make: *** [debian/rules:35: configure-stamp] Chyba 1
    dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build subprocess returned exit status 2
    debuild: fatal error at line 1182:
    dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui -i -b failed
   ```

   However, libtool is already installed. Something to do now? I admit, I have no idea what I am doing, just do not want to switch to WIN10 whenever I want to print anything.

Comment: For any Canon printer see this answer (also works for Ubuntu 20.04):
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261887/canon-g1010-driver-installation-on-ubuntu-20-04/1294113#1294113

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Download these packages:

[https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk/+files/cnijfilter-common-64_3.90-76~ubuntu14.10.1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/%7Emichael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk/+files/cnijfilter-common-64_3.90-76%7Eubuntu14.10.1_amd64.deb)

[https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk/+files/cnijfilter-common-32_3.90-76~ubuntu14.10.1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/%7Emichael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk/+files/cnijfilter-common-32_3.90-76%7Eubuntu14.10.1_amd64.deb)

[https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk/+files/cnijfilter-ip1900series-32_3.90-76~ubuntu14.10.1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/%7Emichael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk/+files/cnijfilter-ip1900series-32_3.90-76%7Eubuntu14.10.1_amd64.deb)

Assuming they are downloaded at ~/Downloads

To install they, run in a terminal:

```
cd ~/downloads
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo apt -f install
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the hint, however it did not helped. If 'll have the time I will reset my system language to english so I could send the entire log, I try to pinpoint the problems - it seems to be whining about dependencies. I tried to solve some, ended up with even more (managed to install libtiff4, now i have problems with pre-dependencies). However the original problem is mainly clash between  cnijfilter-common-64 (3.90-76~ubuntu14.10.1) breaks cnijfilter-common-32. Starting to fear about breaking something which is now working...

Comment: and my attempts managed to ruin the function relataionship my ntb had with the printer at my parent's. So I think I am gonna do what i can to reestablish that one, and give up this one.